# merge pandas dataframes using index vs using data efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, merge, benchmarking

It looks that merge using index is less efficient then merge using data. Am i right? Is that makes any sense?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
rows = 10**5
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(rows,3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])
df1.sort(columns=['A','B'],inplace=True)
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(rows,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])
df2.sort(columns=['A','B'],inplace=True)
times = 10
print 'merge by data: {}'.format(
    timeit.timeit(
        stmt="df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B'],how='outer')",
        setup='from __main__ import df1,df2',number=times)/times)

df1.set_index(['A','B'],inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['A','B'],inplace=True)

print 'merge by index: {}'.format(
    timeit.timeit(
        stmt="df1.merge(df2,right_index=True,left_index=True,how='outer')",
        setup='from __main__ import df1,df2',number=times)/times)
>>> merge by data: 0.0498219966888
>>> merge by index: 0.133691716194
```

Comment: Can you update your pandas (and code) to a newer version? `sort` was deprecated and removed years ago, replaced by `sort_values`.

Comment: Yes, I does appear so.  Probably because your index is a multiIndex.  Secondly, you are probably thinking pandas is similiar to database index.  When actually, in pandas, an index is nothing but a label to the data.  Pandas uses np arrays which are already sequentially placed in memory for efficiency.

Comment: @ScottBoston are you sure? i see that memory usage drops when converting some column into index. so i guess that there is some real indexing method.